# How to display all data using tcpdump?

Tags: linux, networking, tcpdump

I am capturing network traffic by using tcpdump. The problem  is: I can't see all capture data when the package is too long. For example, when the tcp frame length is more than 500, I just see 100-200 or less. How to display all frame data(500+)?

I have tried add `-vv` and `-vvv` parameter. This is my current command:

```
 tcpdump -i eth1 tcp and host 10.27.13.14 and port 6973 -vv -X -c 1000
```

Comment: Did you check with wireshark?

Comment: @mrg I just want to see in the terminal,I am tracing instance traffic.I have no GUI

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Add `-s0` parameter:

```
tcpdump -i eth1 tcp and host 10.27.13.14 and port 6973 -s0 -vv -X -c 1000
```

Comment: `-s snaplen` `--snapshot-length=snaplen` Setting snaplen to 0 sets it to the default of 262144, for backwards compatibility with recent older versions of tcpdump.